# getDownloadURL in array of dictionary (re-rendering issue, forEach)

Tags: reactjs, foreach, firebase-storage, rendering, use-effect

I have an array of dictionaries, (e.g. [{}, {}, {}, {}], each dictionary contains information about book)

I want to download image from firebase storage using `getDownloadURL`. 
My current code's like...

```
const [resObj, setresObj] = useState() // empty variable for update state
let result = []   //create empty array for copy & push new obj

useEffect(() => {
   props.resObj.forEach((obj) => {             // props.resObj: array of dictionary I explained before
            const jpgName = 'bookDB/'+ obj.도서번호 + '.jpg';
            const imgRef = ref(storage, jpgName)
            
            getDownloadURL(imgRef)
                .then((url) => {
                    result1.push({
                        ...obj,
                        bookUrl: url
                    })                    // copy & push dictionary
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    if (error.code === 'storage/object-not-found') {
                        console.log('이미지 파일 없음')
                        result1.push({
                            ...obj,
                            bookUrl: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/No_image_available.svg"
                        })
                    } else { console.log(error)}
                })
            })
        setresObj(result1)
        
    }, [])
```

after this code update 'resObj' variable,
I map resObj in component like...

```
return (
    <div>
        {resObj? resObj.map(item => {
             <img 
                 key = {}
                 className = '~~'
                 onClick = {}
                 src = {item.bookUrl}
             />
        })}
    </div>
)
```

unfortunately.. it doesn't show nothing..

It seems that **forEach**, **useEffect**, **useState**, **getDownloadURL Promise** seriously entangled..  
I tried 1) devide download image code as function, 2) devide download image code as recoil, 3) escape download image code from useEffect, 4) ...(extra variances of code)...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your call to `setresObj` happens before any of the calls to `result1.push` have happened, so you're always setting an empty array. It's easiest to verify this by setting breakpoints and running in the debugger, or by adding some `console.log` calls.

The fix is to use `Promise.all` to wait for all download URLs to have been retrieved and only then call `setresObj`. Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   let promises = props.resObj.map((obj) => {
        const jpgName = 'bookDB/'+ obj.도서번호 + '.jpg';
        const imgRef = ref(storage, jpgName)
        
        return getDownloadURL(imgRef)
            .then((url) => {
                return {
                    ...obj,
                    bookUrl: url
                }
            })  
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error.code === 'storage/object-not-found') {
                    console.log('이미지 파일 없음')
                    result1.push({
                        ...obj,
                        bookUrl: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/No_image_available.svg"
                    })
                } else { console.log(error)}
            })
        })
    Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
        setresObj(results);
    });
}, [])
```

Comment: so sweet...! i really appreciate your comment! I solved this problem!